# Could not find eventmachine-1.2.7, http_parser.rb-0.8.0, sass-embedded-1.64.2, ffi-1.15.5 in locally installed gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, github-pages

I am using bundle to generate GitHub Pages for a repository.

Gemfile

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

# Hello! This is where you manage which Jekyll version is used to run.
# When you want to use a different version, change it below, save the
# file and run `bundle install`. Run Jekyll with `bundle exec`, like so:
#
#     bundle exec jekyll serve
#
# This will help ensure the proper Jekyll version is running.
# Happy Jekylling!



gem "jekyll", "~> 4.3.2"
gem "webrick"        # required when using Ruby >= 3 and Jekyll <= 4.2.2
# gem "github-pages", "~> 228", group: :jekyll_plugins

gem "just-the-docs", "0.5.4" # pinned to the current release
# gem "just-the-docs"        # always download the latest release

gem "jekyll-github-metadata", ">= 2.15"



# If you want to use GitHub Pages, remove the "gem "jekyll"" above and
# uncomment the line below. To upgrade, run `bundle update github-pages`.
# gem "github-pages", group: :jekyll_plugins
# If you have any plugins, put them here!
group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem "jekyll-feed"
end

# Windows and JRuby does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
# and associated library.
platforms :mingw, :x64_mingw, :mswin, :jruby do
  gem "tzinfo", ">= 1", "< 3"
  gem "tzinfo-data"
end

# Performance-booster for watching directories on Windows
gem "wdm", "~> 0.1.1", :platforms => [:mingw, :x64_mingw, :mswin]

# Lock `http_parser.rb` gem to `v0.6.x` on JRuby builds since newer versions of the gem
# do not have a Java counterpart.
gem "http_parser.rb", "~> 0.6.0", :platforms => [:jruby]
```

_config.yml

```
# Welcome to Jekyll!
#
# This config file is meant for settings that affect your whole blog, values
# which you are expected to set up once and rarely edit after that. If you find
# yourself editing this file very often, consider using Jekyll's data files
# feature for the data you need to update frequently.
#
# For technical reasons, this file is *NOT* reloaded automatically when you use
# 'bundle exec jekyll serve'. If you change this file, please restart the server
# process.
#
# If you need help with YAML syntax, here are some quick references for you:
# https://learn-the-web.algonquindesign.ca/topics/markdown-yaml-cheat-sheet/#yaml
# https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/
#
# Site settings
# These are used to personalize your new site. If you look in the HTML files,
# you will see them accessed via {{ site.title }}, {{ site.email }}, and so on.
# You can create any custom variable you would like, and they will be accessible
# in the templates via {{ site.myvariable }}.

title: 5dpo Robotics Team
description: >-                 # this means to ignore newlines until "<item>:"
  "5dpo Robotics Team from the Faculty of Engineering, University of Porto (FEUP)"

baseurl: ""
url: "https://5dpo.github.io"
domain: 5dpo.github.io
repository: 5dpo/5dpo.github.io

permalink: pretty

email: 5dpo@fe.up.pt
twitter_username: ""
github_username: "5dpo"

# Build settings
theme: just-the-docs
plugins:
  - jekyll-feed

exclude:
# from https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/lib/site_template/_config.yml:
  - .sass-cache/
  - .jekyll-cache/
  - gemfiles/
  - Gemfile
  - Gemfile.lock
  - node_modules/
  - vendor/bundle/
  - vendor/cache/
  - vendor/gems/
  - vendor/ruby/
# specific to the theme website:
  - bin/
  - lib/
  - "*.gemspec"
  - "*.gem"
  - LICENSE.txt
  - package.json
  - package-lock.json
  - Rakefile
  - README.md
  - CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
  - docker-compose.yml
  - Dockerfile
# others
  - dev/

# Set a path/url to a logo that will be displayed instead of the title
#logo: "/assets/images/just-the-docs.png"

# Enable or disable the site search
# Supports true (default) or false
search_enabled: true
search:
  # Split pages into sections that can be searched individually
  # Supports 1 - 6, default: 2
  heading_level: 3
  # Maximum amount of previews per search result
  # Default: 3
  previews: 3
  # Maximum amount of words to display before a matched word in the preview
  # Default: 5
  preview_words_before: 5
  # Maximum amount of words to display after a matched word in the preview
  # Default: 10
  preview_words_after: 10
  # Set the search token separator
  # Default: /[\s\-/]+/
  # Example: enable support for hyphenated search words
  tokenizer_separator: /[\s/]+/
  # Display the relative url in search results
  # Supports true (default) or false
  rel_url: true
  # Enable or disable the search button that appears in the bottom right corner of every page
  # Supports true or false (default)
  button: true

# For copy button on code
enable_copy_code_button: true

# By default, consuming the theme as a gem leaves mermaid disabled; it is opt-in
mermaid:
  # Version of mermaid library
  # Pick an available version from https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid/
  version: "9.1.6"
  # Put any additional configuration, such as setting the theme, in
  # _includes/mermaid_config.js
  # See also docs/ui-components/code
  # To load mermaid from a local library, also use the `path` key to specify the
  # location of the library; e.g.
  # for (v10+):
  # path: "/assets/js/mermaid.esm.min.mjs"
  # for (<v10):
  # path: "/assets/js/mermaid.min.js"
  # Note: copy both `mermaid.esm.min.mjs` (v10+) or `mermaid.min.js` (<v10) and
  # the associated `.map` file from thespecified version of `mermaid/dist` to
  # `/assets/js/`.

# Enable or disable heading anchors
heading_anchors: true

# Aux links for the upper right navigation
aux_links:
#   "5dpo on GitHub":
#     - "//github.com/5dpo"

# Makes Aux links open in a new tab. Default is false
aux_links_new_tab: true

# Sort order for navigation links
# nav_sort: case_insensitive # default, equivalent to nil
nav_sort: case_sensitive # Capital letters sorted before lowercase

# External navigation links
nav_external_links:
  - title: 5dpo on GitHub
    url: https://github.com/5dpo

# Footer content
# appears at the bottom of every page's main content

# Back to top link
back_to_top: true
back_to_top_text: "Back to top"

footer_content: "Copyright &copy; 2017-2020 Patrick Marsceill. Distributed by an <a href=\"https://github.com/just-the-docs/just-the-docs/tree/main/LICENSE.txt\">MIT license.</a> <a href=\"https://www.netlify.com/\">This site is powered by Netlify.</a>"

# Footer last edited timestamp
last_edit_timestamp: true # show or hide edit time - page must have `last_modified_date` defined in the frontmatter
last_edit_time_format: "%b %e %Y at %I:%M %p" # uses ruby's time format: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html



# Footer "Edit this page on GitHub" link text
gh_edit_link: true # show or hide edit this page link
gh_edit_link_text: "Edit this page on GitHub"
gh_edit_repository: "https://github.com/5dpo/5dpo.github.io" # the github URL for your repo
gh_edit_branch: "gh-pages" # the branch that your docs is served from
# gh_edit_source: docs # the source that your files originate from
gh_edit_view_mode: "edit" # "tree" or "edit" if you want the user to jump into the editor immediately



# Color scheme currently only supports "dark", "light"/nil (default), or a custom scheme that you define
color_scheme: dark

callouts_level: quiet # or loud
callouts:
  highlight:
    color: yellow
  important:
    title: Important
    color: blue
  new:
    title: New
    color: green
  note:
    title: Note
    color: purple
  warning:
    title: Warning
    color: red

# Google Analytics Tracking (optional)
# Supports a CSV of tracking ID strings (eg. "UA-1234567-89,G-1AB234CDE5")
# Note: the main Just the Docs site does *not* use Google Analytics.
# ga_tracking: UA-2709176-10,G-5FG1HLH3XQ
# ga_tracking_anonymize_ip: true # Use GDPR compliant Google Analytics settings (true/nil by default)

plugins:
  - jekyll-seo-tag
  - jekyll-github-metadata

kramdown:
  syntax_highlighter_opts:
    block:
      line_numbers: false

compress_html:
  clippings: all
  comments: all
  endings: all
  startings: []
  blanklines: false
  profile: false
  # ignore:
  #   envs: all

github: [metadata]



# show_excerpts: true
```

However, I am always obtaining the following error when trying to test the website locally:

```
$ gem install bundler
Fetching bundler-2.4.18.gem
Successfully installed bundler-2.4.18
Parsing documentation for bundler-2.4.18
Done installing documentation for bundler after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
$ bundle install
Bundle complete! 8 Gemfile dependencies, 34 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
$ bundle exec jekyll serve
Could not find eventmachine-1.2.7, http_parser.rb-0.8.0, sass-embedded-1.64.2, ffi-1.15.5 in locally installed gems
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Additional information:

- ruby 3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [x86_64-linux]
- gem -v: 3.2.3
- OS: Kubuntu 20.04 64bit

I tried to remove the Gemfile.lock file and `bundle install` but it did not worked...

Comment: Try to explore `$ gem env` output. And also I would recommend to check your ruby/bundler setup works properly on any other project  on your local machine.